# Wingpanel use high CPU but late show

Tags: wingpanel

When the computer turns on, the menu comes too late. It crashes when I click on notifications when it arrives. Can you help me?

The kernel and elementary version I use:

```
OS: elementary OS 5.1.5 Hera x86_64 
Host: HP EliteBook 840 G4 
Kernel: 4.15.0-108-generic 
Uptime: 2 mins 
Packages: 2381 
Shell: zsh 5.4.2 
Resolution: 1366x768 
DE: Pantheon 
WM: Mutter(Gala) 
Terminal: io.elementary.t 
CPU: Intel i5-7200U (4) @ 3.100GHz 
GPU: Intel HD Graphics 620 
Memory: 1498MiB / 7856MiB
```

[image]

Comment: Why you are using old kernel 4.15 when Elementary OS is using kernel above 5? Any explanation?

Comment: There is nothing I do intentionally. I use `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` How to upgrade?

Comment: Strange. Can you try sudo apt dist-upgrade in terminal?

Comment: `0 packages will be upgraded, 0 new packages will be installed, 0 packages will be removed and 0 packages will not be upgraded.`

Comment: What version are you using Juno or Hera?

Comment: OS: elementary OS 5.1.5 Hera x86_64

Comment: Hm. Then I need to provide one more time the tutorial how to install newer kernel. But this is strange you are using the old one. What entries you have in grub when you start the system? Do you have in Advanced options in grub entries with kernel above 5?

Comment: My systen is also elementary OS 5.1.5 Hera with Linux 4.15.0-108-generic. I don't have problem with wingpanel. Should I upgrade the Kernel?

Comment: MA Jacob no. However if you need you can install newer kernel. On kernel.org you will find the changelog.

Answer (score 0):

Check current kernel with uname -a in terminal and then proceed the kernel upgrade.

```
uname -a
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.3/linux-headers-5.3.0-050300_5.3.0-050300.201909152230_all.deb https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.3/linux-headers-5.3.0-050300-generic_5.3.0-050300.201909152230_amd64.deb https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.3/linux-image-unsigned-5.3.0-050300-generic_5.3.0-050300.201909152230_amd64.deb https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.3/linux-modules-5.3.0-050300-generic_5.3.0-050300.201909152230_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-5.3.0-050300*.deb linux-image-unsigned-5.3.0*.deb linux-modules-5.3.0-050300*.deb
sudo reboot
uname -a
```

Additional knowledge for advanced users which allow to install up to 5.6 version which is stable. 5.7 is in testing (I am using it).

Mainlines:

```
https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.3/
https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.4/
https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.5/
https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.6/
```

Use always amd64 architecture for 64 bit. The exception is when you are using 32 bit architecture, because you have to.

Do not use lowlatency headers and images, because it is for special purpose, when you really need it.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall wingpanel

Type in terminal:

```
sudo apt install libchamplain-0.12-dev libchamplain-gtk-0.12-dev libclutter-1.0-dev libecal1.2-dev libedataserverui1.2-dev libfolks-dev libgee-0.8-dev libgeocode-glib-dev libgeoclue-2-dev libglib2.0-dev libgranite-dev libgtk-3-dev libical-dev meson valac
cd
cd Downloads
wget https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
cd wingpanel-master
meson build --prefix=/usr
cd build
ninja
sudo ninja install
wingpanel
```

Comment: I use `meson build --prefix=/usr`=> `wingpanel-interface/meson.build:58:1: ERROR:  Problem encountered: No supported mutter library found!`

Comment: Try sudo apt install libmutter-2-0 && sudo apt install libmutter-2-dev and then try once again.

Answer (score 0):

For Elementary OS the solution is here:

[https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/stable](https://launchpad.net/%7Eelementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/stable)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```